# move columns forward, after deletion

Tags: jquery

I have a simple table that looks like this

```
<table class="table table-striped">
 <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>941</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When i click on `x` of the 1st `<td>` I'd like delete the contents in that column, then move all the data in column 2 to column 1, and column 3 to column 2.

When i click on `x` of the 2nd `<td>` I'd like delete the contents in that column, then move all the data in column 3 to column 2.

so far i got the delete part working, but cant seem to clone the column and move it. here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkeyevsz/) of what I've done so far.

the idea is to always show 3 columns, but to just move the data forward. and leave deleted columns blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My concept is to identify the index of the column that was clicked and then, for each row, remove the cell at that index and append a blank replacement cell to the end of the row.

Below, I've demonstrated this functionality with multiple tables on the page.

```js
$(function() {

  // selector for all tables on the page
  var $tables = $('table');

  // define the click handler
  $tables.on('click', '[data-toggle="compare-remove"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    // define the clicked element,
    // the clicked table (this code works for multiple independent tables),
    // and index of the clicked column
    var $this=$(this),
        $this_table=$this.closest('table'),
        col_index = $this.parent('td').index();

    // iterate through all rows of the clicked table
    $('tr', $this_table).each(function() {

      // define the current row
      var $this_row=$(this);
      
      // remove the cell at the specified column index
      $this_row.find('td').eq(col_index).remove();
      
      // add a blank cell to the end of the row
      $this_row.append('<td />');
      
    });

  });
  
});
```

```css
table,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Adam</td><td>Smith</td><td>941</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Jill</td><td>Smith</td><td>50</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Eve</td><td>Jackson</td><td>94</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Adam</td><td>Smith</td><td>941</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but how would i add say and image to the second `<td>` that is appended?

Comment: You mean add an image to each blank `<td>` that is added on the right?

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to just hide the column.  Like so:

```js
$(function() {
  $("table").on("click", '[data-toggle="compare-remove"]', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var e = $(this).parents('td').index(),
        i;

    i = e + 1;

    $("table td:nth-child(" + i + ")").hide();

  });
});
```

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
    <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="compare-remove">x</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>941</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkeyevsz/1/)